# Android Manifest file uses sdk and uses permission doubts

Tags: android

i want to submit my android application to google-play.

**my mainfest file is:**

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

i am using the same layout folder for all screens.i didn't kept any seperate folders for large and xlarge screens like layout-xlarge and layout-large.how can i write android mainfest file to support multiple screens. because my xlarge screen is not rendering properly with this mainfest file.

This is my first android app so kindly tell me the way of writing mainfest file to support all **screen-sizes** and all **android os versions**.

Comment: Your issue isn't which screen sizes you support - you've already got that. Your issue (as far as I can tell from your question) is that you're using the same resources for all screen sizes. If your app doesn't render properly with those resources, you need to alter the layout resources so that it does

Comment: how to alter the resource.i need the same design for all screens

Comment: Basically, what the app does when you tell it to use a resource (for example `R.layout.main_screen`, it looks for a layout folder specifying the current configuration (whether that's density, screen size, orientation etc) - for example, if you want a different layout for landscape or portrait orientation you put the portrait layout in `layout-port` and the landscape one in `layout-land`, and the device uses it automatically. You need to alter the design slightly so that it looks right, which depending on how you're laying out will mean changing weights/margins etc

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exampl.eee"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: is there any relation b/w use sdk and support screens

Answer (score 0):

try out this:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: is there any relation b/w use sdk and support screens